Configure handlebars instance using plain nestjs
I'm using Handlebars with NestJS (MVC). Is there a way to pass custom config options (e.g. helpers) to the underlying handlebars instance? I didn't find any options in the docs...
https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mvc
app.useStaticAssets(join(__dirname, '..', 'public'));
app.setBaseViewsDir(join(__dirname, '..', 'views'));
app.setViewEngine('hbs');

